# Unable to Install m2crypto

Tags: python, django, macos, swig, m2crypto

I am unable to install M2Crypto on OSX 10.11.1. I have swig and pcre already installed.

Below is the trace from my installation. Please help !!

```
$ pip install M2Crypto

Collecting M2Crypto
  Using cached M2Crypto-0.22.5.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: M2Crypto
  Running setup.py install for M2Crypto
    Complete output from command /Users/nitish/edmarket/bin/python3.4 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/zw/142ltd2d3t7f8vx3sk_v_fyw0000gn/T/pip-build-wdu6z7dn/M2Crypto/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/zw/142ltd2d3t7f8vx3sk_v_fyw0000gn/T/pip-hgwirik3-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/nitish/edmarket/include/site/python3.4/M2Crypto:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/ASN1.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/AuthCookie.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/BIO.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/BN.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/callback.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/DH.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/DSA.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/EC.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/Engine.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/Err.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/EVP.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/ftpslib.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/httpslib.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/m2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/m2urllib.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/m2urllib2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/m2xmlrpclib.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/Rand.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/RC4.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/RSA.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/SMIME.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/threading.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/util.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto
    copying M2Crypto/X509.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/cb.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/Checker.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/Cipher.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/Connection.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/Context.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/Session.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/ssl_dispatcher.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/SSLServer.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/timeout.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/TwistedProtocolWrapper.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto/SSL
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto/PGP
    copying M2Crypto/PGP/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto/PGP
    copying M2Crypto/PGP/constants.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto/PGP
    copying M2Crypto/PGP/packet.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto/PGP
    copying M2Crypto/PGP/PublicKey.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto/PGP
    copying M2Crypto/PGP/PublicKeyRing.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto/PGP
    copying M2Crypto/PGP/RSA.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto/PGP
    running build_ext
    building 'M2Crypto.__m2crypto' extension
    swigging SWIG/_m2crypto.i to SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c
    swig -python -I/Users/nitish/edmarket/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/include/python3.4m -I/usr/include -includeall -modern -builtin -outdir build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/M2Crypto -o SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c SWIG/_m2crypto.i
    SWIG/_m2crypto.i:31: Error: Unable to find 'openssl/opensslv.h'
    SWIG/_m2crypto.i:45: Error: Unable to find 'openssl/safestack.h'
    SWIG/_evp.i:12: Error: Unable to find 'openssl/opensslconf.h'
    SWIG/_ec.i:7: Error: Unable to find 'openssl/opensslconf.h'
    error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below command to resolve you problem

```
env LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" \
CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" \
SWIG_FEATURES="-cpperraswarn -includeall -I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" \
pip install M2Crypto
```

Comment: You are my life saver, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `openssl-dev` package.

Comment: Can you provide me a link to the installation.

Comment: Actually installed the openssl-dev package, but same result

Comment: Really the same? `Unable to find 'openssl/*.h'`? Did You read https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/blob/master/INSTALL.rst ?